# Servicestack is sending me an error when using GET for Auth

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am getting an error in the JSON JWT Auth.

GET Authenticate requests are disabled, to enable set AuthFeature.AllowGetAuthenticateRequests=true

This worked a few days ago and I cannot figure out what we changed to break it.
I cannot find this property in the auth feature. I even copied the code from the GitHub unit tests. It does not see there is a property for AllowGetAuthenticateRequests in AuthFeature

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new BasicAuthProvider(),                    //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
                new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
                    //HashAlgorithm = "HM256",
                    //PrivateKey = privateKey.ExportParameters(true),
                    AuthKeyBase64 = AppSettings.GetString("jwt.auth.key"),
                    RequireSecureConnection = false,
                    //Turn on for Prod: EncryptPayload = true
                    }, //JWT TOKENS
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings)
            })
        {
            HtmlRedirect = "/",
            //IncludeRegistrationService = true,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [AuthFeature.AllowGetAuthenticateRequests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthFeature.cs#L83) property is a lambda, where you can enable all GET Requests with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    AllowGetAuthenticateRequests = req => true
});
```

If it's not showing up for you then you may have an older pre-release version installed, to install the latest version, [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages):

```
$ nuget locals all -clear
```

Then restore your solution again.